# Apache could host a web server but "php -S" can't

Tags: php, apache

I'm new to web development.

I installed Apache and PHP separately, not using XAMPP. Then I notice that after I create a PHP project, I could put it into `htdocs` folder and launch httpd from Apache and working fine. But if I use `php -S localhost:80 -t my_folder`, no matter which port I'm using, I can't access it via any browser or cURL.

My computer is running Windows 10 with Anniversary update and ZoneAlarm. I'm not quite sure if these information are related. Please let me know if I need to provide more information to identify the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `127.0.0.1` IP instead of localhost

Comment: Thanks @hjpotter92. I have tried, not working for me.